# How do I use a django url inside of an option tag in a dropdown menu?

Tags: html, django, html-select

I have a select tag with two options. I want the url to change based on the option selected. I want the url defined in URLPATTERNS in django to be linked to these options.
My html:

```
 <select name="rec-type" id="rec-type">
    <!-- <a href="{% url 'transactions' rec_type='expense' %}"> -->
    <option value="expense">Expense</option>
    <!-- </a> -->
    <!-- <a href="{% url 'transactions' rec_type='expense' %}"> -->
    <option value="income">Income</option>
    <!-- </a> -->
  </select>
```

My url for transactions is :

```
    path('transactions/<str:rec_type>', views.transactions, name='transactions'),
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried the code in comments, I have tried url in the value part of option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="rec-type" id="rec-type" onchange="location = this.value;">

        <option value="{% url 'transactions' "expense" %}">Expense</option>
        <option value="{% url 'transactions' "income" %}">Income</option>

</select>
```

This should work, you would go to this url when change option